# docker build can't find cache key

Tags: html, docker, dockerfile

project tree

```
- dockerable
-- dock
--- Dockerfile
-- index.html
```

I made a simple website on index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>my journay to dockerising</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>this is an education project by me</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and tried to containerise that using apache2 in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd:2.4.57

WORKDIR /Users/asklipios/Desktop/dockerable

COPY /Users/asklipios/Desktop/dockerable/index.html /

COPY . . 

ENV port = 5000

EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "httdp" ,"start"]
```

but when I run: `docker run -t asklipios/exmple:1.0 /Users/asklipios/Desktop/dockerable`
it gives me this:

```
[+] Building 1.2s (7/8)                             
 => [internal] load build definition from Doc  0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 318B           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/li  0.8s
 => [internal] load build context              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 313B              0.0s
 => CANCELED [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/htt  0.1s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/httpd:2.4.57  0.1s
 => => sha256:a86b8ccb1e65a55 1.86kB / 1.86kB  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] WORKDIR /Users/asklipios/Des  0.0s
 => ERROR [3/4] COPY /Users/asklipios/Desktop  0.0s
------
 > [3/4] COPY /Users/asklipios/Desktop/dockerable/index.html /:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/Users/asklipios/Desktop/dockerable/index.html" not found: not found
```

1. I tried repulling the httdp image
2. I tried googling it
3. I searched on stackoverflow

Comment: I made a typo. I type docker build -t asklipios/exmple:1.0 /Users/asklipios/Desktop/dockerable

Comment: and now it tells:

Answer (score 0):

You can't use absolute paths in the dockerfile; source paths in the dockerfile are relative to [the root of the Docker build context](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/context/).

According [to the docs for the image](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd), you should put your HTML in `/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/`, so the dockerfile should be

```
FROM httpd:2.4.57
COPY ./index.html /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

and your command, assuming your current working directory is where `index.html` is, should be

```
docker build -f dock/Dockerfile .
```

so it uses the current working directory as the Docker build context and `dock/Dockerfile` as the dockerfile.